# fxFlex rules won't apply to mat-sidenav

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-sidenav

I'm trying to center content of . The problem is any rules that I'm trying to apply won't change anything. If I add fxFlex rules to  everything seems to work just fine.
I've tried to apply rules for each element, but still no clue.

the code for the sidenav without any rules:

```
<mat-sidenav-container>

    <mat-sidenav #sidenav opened mode="side">
        <div *ngIf="rooms">
            <div class="mat-title">OBJECTS:</div>
            <mat-nav-list *ngFor="let room of rooms ;trackBy: trackId">
                <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="['/select/room', room.id, 'device' ]">
                    <span class="mat-body-1">{{room.roomName}}</span>
                </a>
            </mat-nav-list>
        </div>
    </mat-sidenav>

    <mat-sidenav-content fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
    ...
    </mat-sidenav-content>

</mat-sidenav-container>
```

screen
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lazyload module, you need to import FlexLayoutModule on that module